# Show that the range of a function $f$ is a set

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation

A function $f$ is defined to be a set of ordered pairs such that whenever $(a,b)\in f$ and $(a,c)\in f$, we have $b=c$.

The range of a function $f$ is defined as $ran(f)=\{b\mid(\exists a)((a,b)\in f)\}$.

There is also a proposition which says an ordered pair $(a,b)$ can be fully described by the set $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$.

The proof is just a single line: $ran(f)=\{\cup\cup f\mid (\exists a)((a,b)\in f)\}$, which is a set because unions of sets are sets by ZFC axioms. What I don't understand is, why is the range of $f$ the union of unions of $f$? I just don't get it.

Comment: The range is a subset of the double union, and you take the double union to get at the elements $a$ and $b$ of the ordered pair so that you have a set of elements from which to pick out the elements of the range, rather than a set of sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The union of $f$ is a set that contains all the sets $a$ as well as all the sets $\{a,b\}$. The union of this, again, is therefore a set that contains, among other things, all the $b$'s. You need to use comprehension to extract the $b$'s alone.

It should've been $$ran(f)=\{b\in \cup\cup f\mid (\exists a)((a,b)\in f)\}$$

Answer (score 2):

This line should probably be as follows, $$\operatorname{ran}(f)=\left\{b\in\bigcup\bigcup f\; \middle|\ \exists a:(a,b)\in f\right\}.$$

The reason being that $\bigcup\bigcup f$ would include all the elements which appear in *either* coordinate of an ordered pair inside of $f$ (this is known also as the "field of $f$"), simply by the Kuratowski coding of ordered pairs into sets. Then using separation, one can actually separate the range from the field.